# Unknown host (my proxy ip). You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle in android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.2

I used to run android studio through a proxy, it was called "wall" so I had it configured that way.

I upgraded to Android Studio 3.2 and additionally had to stop using it so I am connected to the internet through a proxy free connection.

I went to my settings->Appearance&Behaviour->System Settings->HTTP Proxy and set the option to No proxy

I search throughout my project for a reference to wall and I couldn't find anything

However when I try to build, gradle tries to download a file ( 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.2.61/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.61.pom' ) which I can download normally through my browser and I get the `Unknown host 'wall'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.`

I tried with a brand new project and get the same.

I tried deleting the  `C:\Users\(username)\.AndroidStudio3.2` folder and again the same message.

Can someone please provide me with a solution?

Answer (score 1):

After some hours of searching it seems that the problem was that gradle seems to keep a backup of gradle.options (or I may have done it through an option in android studio) in `C:\Users\(username)\.gradle\` so even though I removed all references to my proxy, it still kept those and ignored the `gradle.properties` file in my project.

When I removed the entries to my proxy, it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise config:

DPP config:

IP config:

IP assignment: DHCP

Proxy settings: NONE

cuid=1000 cname=android.uid.system:1000

luid=1000 Iname=android.uid.system:1000

Icuid=1000 userApproved=USER_UNSPECIFIED

nolnternetAccessExpected=false

recentFailure: Association Rejection code: 0

Share ThisAp: false

wifi id: 0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).